# Excel - "Format Cell" to display "FALSE" value in red?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

Excel could define data type and format, just right click an cell and choose "Format cells...".

Inside, it seems you can define conditional format, e.g. if the value is `0` then display in red.

Suppose I have cells with either `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, could it be defined such that, `FALSE` values will be displayed in red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, suppose I have cells with either TRUE or FALSE value,
>   could it be defined such that, "FALSE" values will be display in Red?

**Home Tab**

- Styles Section →
- Conditional Formatting →
- Highlight Cells Rules →
- Equal To →
- Set Rule → Format Cells that are equal to → with Format Drop Arrow for
  formatting.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not? Since you already know Conditional Formatting

1. Pick "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
2. Put `=FALSE` as the formula
3. Click Format, then format it as **red** as you see fit (maybe red fill or red text, but you need to select a suitable fill to improve readibility)

Just use the same method to format `TRUE`, if you want it **blue** or **green** or whatever. You will get two rules, one for red false, and one for true.

Comment: no, i don't want to use "Conditional Formatting" as it soon generates too many formats

Comment: What do you mean by "generating too many formats" ?

Comment: @athos you can use conditional formatting to generate only two formats (Red and not-Red)